How do I place wings on a fuselage for testing?
so I am researching the effects of wing geometry and anhedral angle on RDWs in ground effect using CFD. So far the research articles/papers I've read only test the wing without the fuselage as seen in the first image, link to the paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cja.2022.06.015.

Now, if I were to use and test those wings with a fuselage how should I place it? Should I use method A or B (according to the bottom image, considering the circle/box to be the fuselage)? If I use method B, what should be the reference wing area?

Any advice is accepted, if you have sources to prove the right method that would be useful.

You're doing research. If your research is novel, then it's likely that nobody will know which is the "right" approach. Consider this in the context of a PhD defence and someone asks you why you chose the method you did, would "Somebody on the internet said so" be a satisfactory answer?

@CatchAsCatchCan I agree, I was hoping someone here would know and maybe have a source, or at least help lead me in the right direction since my major is not in aeronautical engineering, thanks for responding though!

@CatchAsCatchCan Do you have any recommended forums/books/journals where I could get advice/information regarding this, I am still an undergraduate and still getting into this so anything would help. Thanks!

The reference area is the one in A, i.e. considering the wing as extending inside the fuselage.

@CatchAsCatchCan any place is good to ask, even for doctoral studies. University cafeteria, the internet, train station toilet.

@sophit Ok thanks, I think It is generally agreed that the correct reference area is the one in A, but what about the anhedral? I think that B makes more sense structurally.

@RDD20: you can just choose one suitable reference and stick with it for all of your experiments.

Bottom line, the fuselage will reduce the cross-sectional area of the wing. My time in areo was long before CFD came along, but the principals will be the same. Without a fuselage, you are modeling lift across the entire wing. With the fuselage, the area taken up by the fuselage will no longer produce lift. Regardless of whether it is high/low wing (modify if fuselage is a "lifting-body" design). I would look for any research that discusses what fraction of the cross-sectional area of the fuselage to reduce lift/ground-effects by.

The conventional way to measure wing area includes the projected vertical area of the fuselage segment between them, either by spanwise line segments or by extending the leading and trailing edges (Peter Kämpf; Leeham News; FAI aeromodelling CIAM rules 2021, B.4.22 "When wings ... are built into the fuselage ... include that area contained within the normal contours of the [wing] extended so as to meet at the plane of symmetry.").
Thus, method B increases the wing area, which would be an unfair comparison to the wing alone.
I wouldn't call method A "right," but it does agree with the literature.

So I assume that the anhedral angle doesn't have to start at the centerline as long as the planform area remains the same? Although it would result in some differences with the experimental results from the paper.
Thanks for the answer btw!

That's right, to avoid comparing apples to oranges.  BTW, how stackexchange works: give us a few more days to post more answers, then click the checkmark to accept the one that best answered your question.

Method A and Method B are obviously going to give different results. Method C could be when the wings join below the fuselage and method D when the wings join above the fuselage.
   O
  / \        /O\
 /   \      /   \
Method C   Method D  

In all four methods, there is only one where the fuselage does not have a significant impact on your results. If you want to research the impact of the fuselage, then you can not use that is the method. If you do not care about the impact of the fuselage, then it is the only method you can use.
